# Sending huge byte array over network

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, compression

I am trying a live stream a mesh generated kinect on unity network, I have successfully sent the mesh but my problem is with it's texture the size of the byte array after converting to jpeg is still huge that it makes the whole process slow, are there any compression techniques for arrays so that it can be sent  efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

```
Texture2D texture = LoadTexture();
byte[] compressedBytes = texture.EncodeToJPG(75);
```

This `byte[]` is compressed already. It's hard to beat lossy compression and compressing it again would probably make little difference.
Maybe cut it's size. Try baking colors into vertex color (if that's acceptable) or send mipmap 3, then 2 then 1 on worker threads.

For general-use `byte[]` lossless compression you can use [LZMA](https://web.archive.org/web/20200314210804/https://www.splinter.com.au/compressing-using-the-7zip-lzma-algorithm-in/).